# Grinding an RRS plate to fit new body

Tags: canon-5d-mark-ii, tripod-heads

I have an L plate for the original 5D. I now have a 5DII. I see how it can fit with a bit of grinding, and read others have done it. Anyone know what is the best tools and such to use? Bench grinder with what kind of material doing the grinding? Then finish with what kind of file to get as smooth a finish and edge as possible?

Comment: Use lots of time and finesse and no matter what tools you use it can come out good. For small work I use a Dremel tool and start with a cutoff wheel to get the dimensions close. A grinding attachement to get the surface curves close, Sanding wheel to get the surface finish close, Polishing Wheel to finish the job.

Comment: If you're using a bench grinder on aluminium, be aware that the wheel is going to clog up **really** fast. Have a grinding wheel dresser on hand.

Answer (score 1):

The plates are aluminum, so as long as you use tools designed for aluminum you should be ok. That said, I've never tried to mod one.

Answer (score 1):

I've used my woodworking tools on aluminum, including a router.  So a mini-router bit for the dremmel (or do you have a laminate trimmer mini-router?) will work, and it uses teeth rather than grit so it won't have a clogging problem.

That also gives a very smooth edge, if guided with a jig.  (My experience is with full-size powerful router mounted under a table)

You can also get a little buffing wheel for a dremmel or drill, which you can use with paste. I've used open-coat non-strerated sandpaper with naptha (you don't need wet/dry paper but just regular paper works, unlike with water) to touch up a little jitter from the cut. I don't know how fine you need for the finish you want: certainly not mirror smooth like my show-off chisels.  At a fancy hardware store or woodworking store you can buy sandpaper by the single sheet, so you can just buy one at a time and stop when it's good enough.
Hmm, slurry from the sharpening wet-stone might work well, if you have something like that.